Template inference when there are multiple possibilities?
I have the following pattern:
struct Wrapper
{
   vector<shared_ptr<BaseType>> data;

   template <typename DerivedType>
   add(const DerivedType& e)
   {
     data.push_back(make_shared<DerivedType>(e));
   };
}

The goal of my Wrapper is to use polymorphism, I want to be able to cast back any e to its DerivedType.
Now, if I have B, a derived class of A, and I do this:
wrapper.add(B());

The type inference could resolve DerivedType as B.

Could template inference resolve DerivedType as A as well since B() has base type A even if it's not its most derived type?
If yes, does make_shared<A>(e) produce a shared pointer that can be dynamically casted into shared_ptr<B>?
If no, do you know a better design than my wrapper to do this? I need the wrapper to be copyable. I can just add with explicit template, but I want to avoid it.


Re: "use polymorphism ... cast back ... to its derived type" -- the purpose of polymorphism is to not have to know the actual derived type and not to cast to it. The base type defines the interface to a family of classes, and derived types implement that interface in various ways.

Side note : It is template deduction.  However your template can accept ANY type. In C++20 you can use concepts to limit what the types can be.

To make sure you get a derived type see: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2f6d452329139d6

@PeteBecker If BaseType is polygon and I want to do something for each square or for each triangle, do I have to implement a method Polygon::isTriangle() ? My goal was to just try to dynamically cast the pointer to avoid such a method.

@NathanOliver I am using boost with a static assert to ensure it is a derived type

@François -- you don't have to do anything. If you need to know about the derived type it's not polymorphism. The question doesn't give enough details about the desired operations to give advice on the merits of various approaches.

"do I have to implement a method Polygon::isTriangle()?" You might already filter by dynamic_cast if really needed. Having several vectors might be more appropriate: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Square>> squares; std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Triangle>> triangles;std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Polygon>> others;.


Could template inference resolve DerivedType as A as well since B() has base type A even if it's not its most derived type?

No. You would have to pass in an actual A variable to make DerivedType deduce as A, or else set DerivedType to A explicitly.

If yes, does make_shared<A>(e) produce a shared pointer that can be dynamically casted into shared_ptr<B>?

No. make_shared() creates exactly what you ask it to create.  In this case, it would create a new A object, which is copy-constructed by slicing e into an A. As there would be no B present in the new A object, you cannot cast it later to a B.
To make that work correctly, you would have to use make_shared<B>() to create a B object, and then assign the result to a shared_ptr<A>, which can then be later casted back to shared_ptr<B> via std::dynamic_pointer_cast.

I edited my question. You confirm than add(B()) will never be compiled as add(B()) ?

That is correct. I updated my answer
